# Code still running in background even after backgroundTimeRemaining is zero?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

```
        UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

        UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task = 0;

        background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{

            [application endBackgroundTask:background_task];
        }];

       SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(action);
       timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:floatUpdateInterval target:self selector:selector userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The above code (timer) is still running even after the backgroundTimeRemaining is 0 (zero).
How could this be? Isn't there a 10 min max for the above type of approach ?

Is the above code considered "app store" safe for submission ?

Comment: I have seen this, too, in iOS 8.  The `backgroundTimeRemaining" counts down from 180 to 0, but the background thread keeps running.

Comment: did you get any answer for it?

Comment: Are you doing anything else in the background like using location services?

Comment: Did you check the expirationhandler is called?

Comment: I have location service on and it does the same thing.  I don't know why??

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a timer that is just scheduled to repeat. beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler will be called when the time is up, this is your chance to stop whatever didn't finish in time.

You should invalidate your timer in beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler.